# Confusion using Multiplication rule in probabilty

Tags: probability

> P(A and B) = P(A|B) * P(B) = P(B|A) * P(A)

For example, rolling two dices at the same time, we treat there are total 36 possible outcomes.

For two dices a,b 
We consider 1,2 and 2,1 as different events. How about 1,1 and 1,1. Why do we consider them as same event rather than two events?

but then

> P(A and B) = 2*P(A)*P(B)

Can anyone clarify my misunderstanding?

Comment: The last equation is not true. You should also define the events A and B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the dices: There is only way that the result (1,1) will occur, namely both dice have rolled a 1, but there are two ways that the result (1,2) will occur, namely (1,2) and (2,1).

If it still confusing, then think that one dice is blue and the other red, so that you can fully distinguish them. To roll (1,1) it means blue has rolled a 1 and red also - and there is no other way - but to roll (1,2) you can have blue 2, red 1 or blue 1, red 2.